# mysql: select * where first and last name starts with the same letter

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

```
SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE first_name like 'm%' and last_name like 'm%';
```

- this selects people with with the same first and last name, but that's for `m` only. How to select all such people from a to z (order by desc is not a matter)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE UPPER(LEFT(first_name, 1)) = UPPER(LEFT(last_name, 1))
```

Explanation: takes the leftmost 1 character of first name and of last name, converts them to uppercase, and compares them.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE LEFT(first_name, 1) = LEFT(last_name, 1);
ORDER BY last_name, first_name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
 from people
 where substring(first_name,1,1) = substring(last_name,1,1)
 order by last_name, first_name
```